# Como definir a função tangente no python?

Tags: python, matemática, matplotlib, numpy, graphics

Gostarei que alguém me ajudasse a definir a função tangente usando o python com restrições em pontos onde a função não existe(pi/2 + k*pi(k inteiro). Desde já obrigado.

Comment: E qual é exatamente sua dúvida ou dificuldade? Já estudou sobre o módulo `math`?

Comment: Você também colocou as tags [tag:matplotlib] e [tag:graphics]. Você quer plotar o gráfico da tangente com os limites ou apenas usar os valores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a biblioteca `math`. Ela tem um comando chamado de `math.tan(x)`, na qual ela retorna o arco tangente de x em radianos.

Exemplo:

```
import math

math.tan(30)

>>> -6.40533119665
```